# Nested AJAX call success function does not get run

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following ajax call nested inside another, but after the first one gets run, nothing gets logged to the console meanwhile it should. Where is the issue?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://ck:8081/get-username",
    type: "get",
    success: function (response) {
        userName = response
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://ck:8081/new-chatuser?username=" + userName,
            type: "get",
            success: function (response) {
                console.log('response' + response)
                $('onlineMembers').append(response)
            }
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: might be bcoz you never it success scenario. Try to add a `failure` case and try to log. Also try to use different variable names for `response` as they are nested within one another.

Comment: presumably one of them is failing. You need to do some basic debugging, so as a first step check your console and network tabs in the browser's developer tools for errors, and non-200 response codes.

Comment: `$('onlineMembers')` should be `$('#onlineMembers')` or `$('.onlineMembers')`

Comment: This is going towards js callback hell. Why not make a named function that handles the second ajax request called 'handleResponse'? Then you could call it from the success funct of the first ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

There is most likely a failure in one of the requests you are sending, to remedie to that, you need to handle the errors as described in the code below :

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://ck:8081/get-username',
    type: 'get',
    success: function(response1) {
        console.log(`First succeeded : ${response2.toString()}`);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://ck:8081/new-chatuser?username=' + response1,
            type: 'get',
            success: function (response2) {
                console.log(`Second succeeded : ${response2.toString()}`);
                $('onlineMembers').append(response2);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(`Second failed : ${error.toString()}`);
            }
        });
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(`First failed : ${error.toString()}`);
    }
});
```

You may want to change `$('onlineMembers')` because I don't think the selector you are using is correct.